# UTF-8 string wrongly encoded somewhere

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a column, `title`, which is of the format CHAR(50) utf_genral_ci. I have a php script that successfully inserts a new row with the `title` value "Bjørn".

The problem occurs when I want to pull it out again. Once it is assigned to a variable the string is "BjÃ¸rn".

Some have pointed me towards mb_*(), however since it's not a problem when I am retrieving it from a form and inserting it, but only when I retrieve it from mysql, I dont believe that can be it.

I have made sure that it is in fact encoded correctly in mysql, and server, database, table, column and connection are ALL UTF-8.

Please someone save me from this nightmare!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try executing these two queries *before* performing your select query: `set names utf8` and `set character set utf8`

Comment: Did you have checked your page encoding? What is comes as in Firefox->view->content encoding by default!

Comment: What @Satya says. Your output encoding might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be because I used the php function htmlentities() on my string. Very weird since last I tried, it also output wrong straight from the database.

I have been having problems with this all day, so the solution to one problem has caused another.

Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value in database using an admin tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench? If it is not displayed correctly, try converting the name to utf-8 using `iconv ($in_charset, 'utf-8', $str)`. If it is correct, make sure that the encoding in your browser is set to UTF-8.